# Call synchronously recursively function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, recursion, mongoose

I'm developing MEANJS project. Here a function which return array by fetch data recursively. Now, I have the problem that how to get that array.

Problem:-

let users **A** have properties is {_id:'001',rmUserId:'001'}, **B**:{_id:'002',rmUserId:'001'}, **C** {_id:'003',rmUserId:'002'}, **D** {_id:'003',rmUserId:'001'}, **E** {_id:'004',rmUserId:'009'}

if user **A** will login then `allUnderUsers` array have **B,C,D** users. That means all users have to follow an own hierarchy.

```
   A
  / \
 B   D
/
C
```

Here is my code:-

```
module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser, callback) {
    try {
        var allUnderUsers = [];
        function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
            User.find({ rmUserId: rmId, isAlive: true, status: 'active' })
                .exec(function(err, users) {
                    if (err)
                        return callback(err)
                    if (users.length > 0) {
                        users.forEach(function(ele, i) {
                            allUnderUsers.push(ele);
                            __getUserByRmId(ele.rmUserId);
                        });
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
        }
        __getUserByRmId(currentUser._id);
    } catch (e) {
        callback(e)
    }
}
```

Here I need to get **allUnderUsers** array after all recursive function called.

I have use callback function like:-

```
....
...
__getUserByRmId(currentUser._id);
callback(null,'done');
.
.
```

but it throws an error i.e,

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
>
> .at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/clsah/projects/LMS/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
>   ........ .......

Comment: What is `return reject(err)` doing in your code?  There is no `reject()` function defined anywhere in your code.  It looks like you're trying to mix callbacks and promises without actually doing either of them correctly.

Comment: sorry for misspelled. I have edited them. please check now. Basically, I need to use `callback` function after all functions are called.

Comment: You need to somehow know when the recursion is done and do `callback(null, allUnderUsers)`.  It looks like `__getUserBYRmId()` will need its own callback to tell you when it's done and, if implemented properly, the callback passed to the top level call of that function will tell you when the recursion is done.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for the reply, But I am not clear. I have edited question again now for more clear. Please check.

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?  This will be a lot easier if we can use the promise support built into the latest version.

Comment: `"mongoose": "^4.5.0"`

Comment: Can you please put the whole error log? It might be helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take advantage of the promises built into the later versions of mongoose and surface a promise interface from your module, you can do this:

Simulated running code here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zr6ynmsu/

```
module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser) {
    function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
        // return promise here
        return User.find({ rmUserId: rmId, isAlive: true, status: 'active' }).exec().then(function(users) {
            if (users.length > 0) {
                let promises = [];
                users.forEach(function(ele, i) {
                    promises.push(__getUserByRmId(ele.rmUserId));
                });
                // return promise which will chain it to original promise
                // this is the key to getting the master promise to wait
                // for everything to be done
                return Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
                    // add in previous results
                    // flatten all the results together into a single array
                    // and remove empty results
                    results.unshift(users);
                    return [].concat.apply([], results.filter(item => item.length > 0));
                });
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
    return __getUserByRmId(currentUser);
}
```

And, then you would use it like this:

```
const someModule = require('yourModule');

someModule.getUnderUsersByRm(someUser).then(results => {
    // process all results here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

---

If you still want your callback interface on getUnderUsersByRm, you can still do that (though if you're doing more than a few async calls, it really is worth using promises for all async operations):

```
module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser, callback) {
    function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
        // return promise here
        return User.find({ rmUserId: rmId, isAlive: true, status: 'active' }).exec().then(function(users) {
            if (users.length > 0) {
                let promises = [];
                users.forEach(function(ele, i) {
                    promises.push(__getUserByRmId(ele.rmUserId));
                });
                // return promise which will chain it to original promise
                // this is the key to getting the master promise to wait
                // for everything to be done
                return Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
                    // add in previous results
                    // flatten all the results together into a single array
                    // and remove empty results
                    results.unshift(users);
                    return [].concat.apply([], results.filter(item => item.length > 0));
                });
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
    __getUserByRmId(currentUser).then(result => {
        callback(null, result);
    }).catch(err => {
        callback(err);
    });
}
```

---

If your user tree is circular, then you can protect against an infinite loop by keeping track of all the visited users.  You need some sort of unique key that identifies each user.  Since I don't know what that is in your program, I will assume the user you are passing  in is already an id.  Any property that uniquely identifies the user will work in this scheme:

```
module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser) {
    let visitedUsers = new Set();

    function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
        // return promise here
        return User.find({ rmUserId: rmId, isAlive: true, status: 'active' }).exec().then(function(users) {
            if (users.length > 0) {
                let promises = [];
                users.forEach(function(ele, i) {
                    // make sure we aren't already processing this user
                    // avoid circular loop
                    let userId = ele.rmUserId;
                    if (!visitedUsers.has(userId)) {
                        visitedUsers.add(userId);
                        promises.push(__getUserByRmId(userId));
                    }
                });
                // return promise which will chain it to original promise
                // this is the key to getting the master promise to wait
                // for everything to be done
                return Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
                    // add in previous results
                    // flatten all the results together into a single array
                    // and remove empty results
                    results.unshift(users);
                    return [].concat.apply([], results.filter(item => item.length > 0));
                });
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
    return __getUserByRmId(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: it has not call in final callback either in catch block, traped in infinite loop.

Comment: @vineetsah - Where did you think there was an infinite loop?  I don't understand your comment.  I am assuming that your user tree is not circular (which would cause an infinite loop).  Even that can be fixed by keeping a Set of visited user names, but your original implementation and your diagram did not show that so I did not implement that type of circular protection.

Comment: @vineetsah - My first code block returns a promise.  The caller of the function uses the promise to retrieve the results (as shown in my example).  It does not pass or use a callback.  My second example shows the old-style callback.  You really should switch to promises for all async development.  It is so much easier to program once you learn it - particular in cases like this when there are multiple async operations that you need to coordinate and need to propagate errors.

Comment: @vineetsah - I added a third option that protects against a circular loop of users.  I assumed your data was not organized in a circular fashion, but your insistence on an infinite loop makes me think maybe your data has that design so I've offered a solution to that.  In that third option, we keep track of all userId values we've already processed and only processed users we haven't yet done.

Comment: it does not return result. changes code http://pastebin.com/Kg36TQey. I think, i missed somethings.

Comment: @vineetsah - Yes, there were some problems in the code where it wasn't returning cumulative results (hard to write perfect code when you can't run it to test).  Here's a runnable version with corrections: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zr6ynmsu/.  I will correct my answer to work like this one does.

Answer (score 1):

### Use [`async.until`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#until) and maintain an array of element to be processed

```
var async = require('async');

module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser, callback) {
  try {
    var allUnderUsers = [];
    var usersToProcess = [currentUser._id]; // Array to track what was earlier done with recursion

    async.until(function() { // Test function for async.until
      return usersToProcess.length === 0;
    }, function __getUserByRmId(callback2) { // fn for async.until
        User.find({
            rmUserId: usersToProcess.shift(), // Take first element of array
            isAlive: true,
            status: 'active'
          })
          .exec(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
              return callback2(err)
            if (users.length > 0) {
              users.forEach(function(ele, i) {
                allUnderUsers.push(ele);
                usersToProcess.push(ele.rmUserId);
                // __getUserByRmId(ele.rmUserId); // To Remove
              });
              return callback2(); // Always call callback;
            } else {
              return callback2(); // Earlier: return false; Return some err argument if you want
            }
          })
    }, callback); // Final callback for async.until
  } catch (e) {
    callback(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I need somethings like this. But, it never calls final callback.

Comment: It is called in line above `catch`. If it is not calling, can you put in some logs to check `usersToProcess.length` at top of `__getUserByRmId` function

Comment: it will call itself in infinite call.

Comment: when i put `console.log(usersToProcess)` at top of `__getUserByRmId` as you say then it call continuously itself it, trap in infinite loop.

Comment: It should call itself till you hierarchy is covered but not infinitely. There might be some bug though. In every iteration, 1 element should be removed from array by `.shift()` and some elements should be appended using `.push()`. `async.until` should exit when array length is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133868/discussion-between-vineet-sah-and-sangharsh).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement the solution using `async` based approach. You may find it naive, but it should work.

```
function __getUserByRmId(rmId, cb) {
  var allUnderUsers = [];
  User.find({ rmUserId: rmId, isAlive: true, status: 'active' })
      .exec(function(err, users) {
        async.each(users, function(user, callback){
          if (user._id != rmId){
            // recursive call 
            __getUserByRmId(user._id, function(childUsers){
              childUsers.forEach(function (childUser) {
                allUnderUsers.push(childUser);
              });
              callback(); //intermediate callback for async call  
            });
          } else { //condition check to avoid infinite loop
            allUnderUsers.push(user);
            callback(); //intermediate callback for-loop 
          }

        }, function(err){
            cb(allUnderUsers);  //final callback with result
        });
      });
}


module.exports.getUnderUsersByRm = function(currentUser, callback) {
  __getUserByRmId(currentUser._id, callback)
};
```

Logically, it should work. Please give a try and let me know, if there are any issue. For now, it returns array containing parent as well. e.g. [A, B, C, D] for your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are getting that error because you run `__getUserByRmId` function (which inside calls the `callback` function if an error occurs, and then, besides anything that happen you call the `callback` function again, which may be sending multiple responses to one same request, and so on, setting headers multiple times even when the response was already sent.

I should have post this in the comments but don't have enough reputation to do so